# Detect last slide in embedded presentation (iframe from Google Slides, SlideShare, etc)

Tags: javascript, iframe, window, google-slides

Scenario: In my HTML page, I have a Google Slide presentation embedded through his embed `<iframe>` code.

E.g.

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/e/2PACX-1vSftNeCXyF6RASNWr9KebUd2ZKx1X--T_2WWlLeRuuCqzG_xnPe53udDb51ISJ_4xKbZtlOn5sPN12L/embed?start=false&loop=false&delayms=3000" frameborder="0" width="960" height="569" allowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

On page load, a separate button below this `<iframe>` will be disabled. I'm looking for a way to detect when the presentation is in his last slide, to then enable this action button from below.

How to accomplish this from JavaScript?